# Passing parameters in url of c# soap web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am working on a c# soap web service. The web service is used by other C# windows programs as well as PHP web pages. I need to pass a paramater in the url of the web service that the c# windows programs or the php scripts use to connect to the web service. I was thing of being able to do something like:

> http://MyWebService.asmx?myParam=true&myOtherParam=false

If I used the method above how would I go about getting the paramaters that are in the URL from the c# web service.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can't you read them from `Request.QueryString`?

Comment: I did try that but not sure what the namespace was, I did look it up but it only seemed to be available for ASP.net pages

Comment: It is in System.Web namespace. You can access it like `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`

Comment: @Suhas yes you are right. Cheers for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access them in QueryString. To access the query string use `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend looking at [Restful WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx).

Your service contract will look something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IYourService
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "YourMethod?myParam={myParam}&myOtherParam={myOtherParam}")]
    void YourMethod(bool myParam, bool myOtherParam) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to call it this way, the parameter names should match those expected by the webservice. You also need to include your method name, e.g.:

```
http://MyWebService.asmx/MyMethodName?myParam=true&myOtherParam=false
```

Comment: When you say the method name, could this be the name of the constructor that is used when the service is first used.

Comment: Do you not have a method (function) in your web service decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute?

Comment: Yea I do, but I thought it would be simpler to set variables from the parameters in a constructor then modifying several methods which is what I would need to do

Comment: Whichever method you want to call (the one that has that attribute) should be specified in your URL.